# my NSIS installer doesn't always extract all files

Tags: file, installation, extract, nsis

I use the NSIS "File" command in order to extract about 1000 files. I've written a simple script in Python, which runs the installer 1000 times, and I've run it. 156 of the installations have finished with not all of the files extracted. I haven't found this problem (or any similar one) in Google. I'll appreciate any help.

Edit - the relevant code:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR

SetOverwrite on

File /r "..\resources\${VERSION}\*"
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Perhaps you could post your calling python code... Do you wait that each installer has finished before starting a new one? Failing to extract a file could happen if the file is locked (= in use).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found a workaround for my case.
In my case, the ~1000 files are divided within several directories under the "..\resources\${VERSION}" directory, so instead of executing one File command on the main directory, I've executed the File command on each inner directory seperately, and it has worked (1,000 installations out of 1,000 installations). 
I guess it's "hard" for the File command to extract ~1000 files at once.

Comment: Sounds weird. I deploy a perl distribution that contains more than 1000 files without any problem. I doubt that a task could be "hard" to do: it just succeeds or it fails. Difficulty is a human consideration.